# JavaFX controller is always null

Tags: java, javafx

I'll try to get in JavaFX 2 and used a simple demo app.
The Project consists of 3 Files, the Main.java, the Controller.java and the sample.fxml.

In Sample.fxml i declared the controller:

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

And in my Main.java I try to access the controller

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(loader.getController()); //prints always null
```

So my first idea was that the mapping doesn't work. So I added a initialize method in the controller.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    System.out.println("init");
}
```

The output is now:

> init
>
> null

So my Question now is how can i access the controller of a given fxml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method is a static method. So when you execute

```
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
  Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

you are not loading the FXML file from the instance of the FXMLLoader that you constructed ("loader"). (You're actually invoking the static method through an object reference.) Hence the loader's controller never gets initialized.

You need

```
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
  Parent root = loader.load();
```

This constructs a loader with a location specified, and then the `load()` method, which is not a static method, is properly invoked on the FXMLLoader instance. Then

```
System.out.println(loader.getController());
```

will give the correct result.

Comment: Thanks! Hope the loader gets improved in the releases to come.

Comment: @Houston What improvement do you think it needs?

Comment: @James_D Looks like many ppl don't immediately realize that load is a static method hence causing confusion. The api should avoid this confusion? Just a thought... All is well now though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to James_D's answer, I recommend to use the fx:root construct. Then you can inject the custom control (implemented by a controller) in another controller using the @FXML annotation.

Comment: Please can you explain the fx:root construct?

Comment: @reikla a simple search for "fx:root tutorial" will get you a couple of links, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm If you have a specific question, please come back and ask a new question.

Comment: "the controller property of FXMLLoader doesn't get set when loading an FXML file" is completely incorrect. As long as you invoke the load() method on the FXMLLoader instance, it will be set.

Comment: Thanks! Thats another way i think. But I prefere James_D's solution!